# Python request() to get json giving different body in browser than in script

Tags: python, json, request

I'm trying to get a json from this URL doing a request with python. Problem is that I'm getting a different body if I use a browser than if I use a python request. The URL is the follwing:

https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/nosumable

The body contains the json I want to download.

This is the code I'm using to get the json:

```
import requests as rq
import json

r=rq.get("https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/nosumable")

print(r.text)
```

In the body I receive a totally different info. What can I do to get the JSON with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a user agent to your `GET` requests.

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}
r = rq.get(
"https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/nosumable", 
headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: cause I started exams, left this project to a side, returned today and the User-Agent is not working, updated it to the new one, but its not working. Can you help me?